# How to extract final line from this IP list?

Tags: dns, batch, ip, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to get the external IP address of a network to see if it is on the same network as other PCs, but my script isn't working. My main problem is that: **No matter what I do I can't seem to get the line with the external ip address from `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`**  Here is what I have:

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com>IP
set nu1m=0
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (IP) do (set /a nu1m+=1 & if !num!==6 set ip=%%A)
echo %ip% >Out.txt
EndLocal
```

I've tried replacing `%ip%` with `!ip!` but no matter what I do the ip variable is empty. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try omitting and not using any of the conditional `IF` and `SET /A` logic and simply try `for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (IP) do set ip=%%A` and then check `%ip%` and see if it's the expected result. Since you are using the `set` command, it will set the last token from the nslookup command which should be the last IP from its output which is what I think you need so give that a try as it may be as simple as that rather than trying to count up and then only set the last output which would be `6` if I understand the logic correctly but it shouldn't be needed actually.

Comment: To remove the extra colon / spaces try [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677062/6811411).

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I'm a fool that is perfect thank you!

Comment: And thanks @LotPings, would you mind rephrasing that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad to help regardless for simple things like that when I can. Sometimes overlooking simple things is very easy to do—I've done it many times myself over complicating solutions because I forgot to try the simple stuff first... Cheers!!

Comment: Totally Happens all the time for me of course :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `nslookup` output to a file you can parse it directly with a `for /f` as shown in [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677062/6811411) I repeat here for easier lookup:

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (
  'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:"'
) Do set ExtIP=%%A
Echo External IP is : %ExtIP%
```